# Get direction on a laptop with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, gps

I have a laptop (Windows) in a car and I want to use it with Google Maps to get my directions.

Unfortunately, it's not always the same person who uses the car, and all the user of the car don't have a Google account + cellphone (or time to sign in when it's an emergency).

Is it possible to get the exact position of the car (and the laptop) by the other device so every driver will be able to use the get direction of Google Maps? Maybe a USB GPS?

i know that USB GPS exist... My question is : did anybody know if i can use a USB GPS plugg in my lap top to get direction in google map before i spent 100 $ to test it ? Normaly google map is using your google account (so your cell phone as you're login)  to get your location. If I can't use cell phone and google account for many reasons...  is google map will know my location using this USB GPS?

Comment: most smartphones have gps it can also give your gps position with apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digrasoft.mygpslocation&hl=en_US can give you lat/lng values.

Comment: unfortunatly for many reason i can't use smartphone... but thank you

Answer (score 0):

A quick internet search of the phrase "USB GPS" reveals that there are many products for less than $100 that plug into a USB port and provide GPS signal.

So, the answer to your question is "yes" and also, "let me google that for you."

Comment: Thank you, I already google it... My question is more : dit a USB GPS work to get direction in google map? Did somebody try it ?